# Angular e2e testing after production with VSTS pipelines

Tags: angular, azure-devops, e2e-testing, angular-e2e

I'm using VSTS build and release pipeline to deploy my angular application.
there is 3 ways to run e2e tests:

1- **In the build pipeline** after installing npm and angular dependencies.

2- **In the release pipeline** after the deployment of my application.

3- **Locally** before using VSTS pipelines.

**If i run it in the build pipeline:**
How can i serve the angular app on certain port so that i can run the e2e on it during the build process in VSTS?

**If i run it in the release pipeline:**
The deployed app won't have the npm dependencies just have the dist folder so that i can't run ng e2e there.

**If i run it locally:**
This is time consuming and not preferred.

What is the best common way to run it?

Comment: Did you check this article? https://medium.com/@danharris_io/how-to-setup-angular-e2e-tests-on-vsts-ci-be0872f9dc31

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't advise on trying to run E2E tests on the Release Pipelines as these should be used to deploy a built app.

One common approach i have come across and use is to have 'E2E' tests run overnight or at a scheduled time daily due to it being a time consuming test and we don't want to block our build agents.

If you have any unit tests i would run these as part of the Build pipeline.

If you run the E2E in VSTS you will need to make sure you include the steps to do an NPM install and then the correct NG command to run the E2E test. If you use Microsoft Provided Build Agent it should already include Google Chrome for you to test with. Hope this helps.